# Unity is returning material color slightly wrong

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this mini task in my game where you need to click trophies to change color of the wood on them. I have two arrays of colors, one is an array containing all possible colors and the other one contains four colors (the answer) as follows:

[image]

I've double checked that the colors are equal between the two arrays. For example the purple in `Colors-array` has **exactly the same** r, g, b & a values as the purple in the `Right Order-array`.

To check whether the trophies has correct color I just loop through them and grab their material color. Then I check that color against the `Right Order-array` but it's not quite working. For example when my first trophy is purple it should be correct, but it's not because for some reason Unity is returning slightly different material color than excepted:

[image]

Hope somebody knows why this is happening.

Comment: Does the materials are same or different ones? I mean for the purple let's say, in Color array and Right Order array. Do they share the material?

Comment: Neither of the arrays have material, just colors as "public Color[] colors"

Comment: So you compare trophy's material color and your color array. First log belongs to trophy's material color and the second one is from array then?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say, they are exactly same color, I assume you are referring `rgb` values from Color Inspector, which are not precise values.

Now I dont know what could be causing in different values of colors but
You can write an extension method to compare the values after rounding them to closest integer.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool CompareRGB(this Color thisColor, Color otherColor)
    {
        return 
            Mathf.RoundToInt(thisColor.r * 255) == Mathf.RoundToInt(otherColor.r * 255) &&
            Mathf.RoundToInt(thisColor.b * 255) == Mathf.RoundToInt(otherColor.b * 255) &&
            Mathf.RoundToInt(thisColor.g * 255) == Mathf.RoundToInt(otherColor.g * 255);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Color red = Color.Red;
red.CompareRGB(Color.Red); // true;
red.CompareRGB(Color.Green); // false;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a palette.  This is simply an array of all the possible colors you use (sounds like you have this).  Record, for each "trophy", the INDEX into this array, at the same time you assign the color to the renderer.  Also, record the index for each "button", at the same time you assign the color to the renderer.

Then you can simply compare the palette index values (simple integers) to see if the color matches.